# MySql reclaim blob space with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to build a table that will contain a large BLOB that will take up 98% of the row size.  However, this BLOB will only be kept temporarily in the row and will be moved to another location and then the BLOB column will be set to NULL.  Can MySQL reuse this space or will it always be part of the row?  If it can not be automatically re-used, is there another way (say an optimize table) that I can use to manually reclaim this space?  If not, I may need to find another solution for handling this particular set of data.

Comment: Can you store it outside MySQL, let's say Redis or another key/value store?

Comment: The data will be moved off to other storage (S3) via batched async process.  The initial write must be mysql for transactional purposes.  I could move it to another store such as Redis (or durable message queue) during the transaction, but this process has to be a fast path so I am hesitant to add other moving parts.  That's why I am focused on whether/how the space can be reclaimed once the BLOB is moved to S3.  If there is absolutely no way to reclaim, then Redis will probably be next option since it is part of our architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will definitely be better off using Redis or even just storing your blob on the file system. This is in fact what I recommend; save the data on a file and place the filename on the table. After async upload to s3 has completed set it to null. If you are using a file system optimized to handle large objects, this will always be faster than an insert into a database.

How exactly blobs are stored depends not just on the length of the data but also on the version of mysql that you are actually using. Deleted rows can always be reused and when subsequent inserts don't reuse the space, it can be recovered with optimize table. But optimize table will take a lock on that table. So you are slowing down the system a second time.

Comment: I actually like the idea of saving the blob to our SAN.  In order to keep our speed consistent, we break the process into two threads - one that saves mysql data and one that saves the blob to the file system (actually SAN).  Since they operate in parallel, its as fast as saving everything entirely to mysql.  Then we have a vacuum process that moves the file to S3 and marks the new location to the mysql audit record.  Seems to work like a charm, even after tested under our expected load.